# Selenium: How do I navigate to a new page and do assertions there?

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, junit

I'm new to Selenium. I'm currently trying to test a web application.

I want to click a button on the start page, which navigates me to a login page. There I'd like to enter my credentials and click the login button. This leads me to a page where I'd like to assert some things.

The problem is, that whenever I've navigated to a new page, I the test doesn't work as expected. Example: I get to the Login Page, but then the input fields aren't filled in. If I go to the Login page directly, it works.

I assume this is a test case that many people will have had, so there must be a simple solution to it, but I just can't manage to find one. I'd really appreciate any help a lot.

Here is my test code:

```
public class AdminTest {
    protected WebDriver driver; 

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/bin/chromedriver");
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();

        this.driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);    

    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        if (driver != null) {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void viewOrderListTest() {

        // this leads to the start page
        this.driver.get("http://localhost:8080/eStore/");
        this.driver.manage().window().maximize();

        // I click the link to the Login page, so far so good
        this.driver.findElement(By.id("link_to_login")).click();

        this.driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        // the keys are NOT entered
        WebElement username = this.driver.findElement(By.id("username"));

        username.click();
        username.clear();
        username.sendKeys("admin");

        WebElement password = this.driver.findElement(By.id("password"));
        password.click();
        password.clear();
        password.sendKeys("admin");

        // This button gets clicked by the test
        this.driver.findElement(By.id("submit_button")).click();

        // this is on the next page, but the test doesn't get that far
        this.driver.findElement(By.id("link_to_admin_page")).click();
```

Edit: The error I'm getting is that first the page tells me that the credentials are wrong (of course, because both fields are empty), so I stay on the Login page, and the exception is a NoSuchElement exception for an element that's on the page after the login.

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"link_to_admin_page"}
```

Edit2: I've tried to insert a wait before looking for the username field, but that didn't change anything.

```
     WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("username")));
```

Edit3: The html class with "link_to_admin_page" (shortened). As far as I see it, the test just never gets beyond the login page, so it doesn't reach this point.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java"%>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

<title>eStore</title>
<body>
    <div class="navbar-wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
                <div class="container">
                    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">

                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                            <c:if test="${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name != null}">
                                <c:if
                                    test="${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name  == 'admin'}">
                                    <li><a id="link_to_admin_page" href="<c:url value="/admin" />">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>&nbsp; Admin</a></li>
                                </c:if>
                            </c:if>

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>

        </div>
    </div>

    <br/><br/><br/>
```

Comment: Are you getting `NoSuchElement Exception` when the test failed?

Comment: @supputuri Yes, exactly. I added the information to the question.

Comment: @Dreana Did you try to wait until the element is present on the page?

Comment: @Fenio I have tried this: wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("username")));

Comment: @Dreana but this is not the element that's failing. Can you also share the HTML of the page with `link_to_admin_page` element?

Comment: I've added it to the question @Fenio

Comment: Try to `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("link_to_admin_page")));`

Comment: This also didn't work for me, but this.driver.navigate().refresh(); did (possibly not the best solution there is though...) Thank you @Fenio